# Android [SupportMapFragment] The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services, supportmapfragment

```
public class PlaceMapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place_maps, container,
                false);


        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        return v;
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapView) findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title(
                "Marker"));
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type PlaceMapsFragment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, All Fragments do not have a native `findViewById()` method. This is why you have to use the onCreateView() method.

This means that you should change `setUpMapIfNeeded()` to `setUpMapIfNeeded(View view)` and in `onCreateView()` pass off v to your modified method. You also need to change `mMap = ((MapView) findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();` to `mMap = ((MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can subclass the `SupportMapFragment` class.

To get a new instance of the `SupportMapFragment` you call `SupportMapFragment.newInstance` and this returns your object.

If you subclass it and call, for example, `PlaceMapsFragment.newInstance()` you're still going to be returning a `SupportMapFragment` object.

If you want to manipulate the map programmatically, I suggest you do the following.

```
this.mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
MapHandler mMapHandler = new mMapHandler(this.mSupportMapFragment.getMap());
```

Hope this helps.